# What kind of iteration should I use for LinkedList?

Tags: java, iterator, linked-list

I know that traversing `LinkedList` by indexing is bad, because list.get(n) is executed in linear time O(n). Thus i shouldn't use indexing. I looked at the `AbstactList.Itr` that is returned by `iterator()` call, it uses `get(cursor)` too. I'm confused.

As pointed out by @axtavt , `LinkedList.iterator()` actually calls `listIterator()` which returns `AbstactList.ListItr` which extends `AbstactList.Itr` and it only adds implementations of `ListIterator` interface. Thus the machinery for getting next element is still the same as in `AbstactList.Itr`. `` `AbstactList.Itr ``'s `next();` calls `get(n)` on the specified list.

Comment: `LinkedList.iterator()` doesn't return `AbstractList.Itr`, it returns `LinkedList.ListItr`, which doesn't use `get()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LinkedList inherits not only from `AbstractList`, but also from `AbstractSequentialList` which in turn implements `iterator()` like this:

```
public Iterator<E> iterator() {
    return listIterator();
}
```

and the `ListIterator` returned by `LinkedList` is smart about using sequential access.

So whether you use foreach, `iterator()` or `listIterator()`, you are always dealing with the same smart iterator type.

Comment: `listIterator()` return `AbstractList.ListItr` which doesn't differ from `AbstactList.Itr` in it's `next()` method.

Comment: @gasan that's not quite correct. `AbstractList.listIterator()` calls `listIterator(0)`, which in turn is overridden by `LinkedList` and returns  `LinkedList.ListItr`

Comment: Thanks, you're right, `LinkedList` has it's own `LinkedList.ListItr` that takes next element without using get. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3):

The best iteration over *any* `List` (actually even *any* `Iterable`) is the [for each](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html) loop:

```
for(Element e : myList){
    // do something
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The foreach loop is very efficient, and easy:

```
List<String> list = new LinkedList<String>();
list.add("First");
list.add("Second");
list.add("Third");
list.add("Fourth");

for(String s : list) {
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

Comment: for-each is only hiding iterator

Answer (score 2):

You should use a foreach loop if you can - that's the most efficient:

```
List<Item> myList = ...;

for (Item item : myList) {
  ...
}
```

If you need to modify the list inside the loop, or traverse through multiple collections in one loop, use an iterator:

```
List<Item> myList = ...;
Iterator<Item> it = myList.iterator();

while (it.hasNext()) {
  Item item = it.next();
  ...
}
```

And if you need to traverse backwards, or something else specific to linked lists, use `listIterator`:

```
ListIterator<Item> it = myList.listIterator();
...
```

Comment: for-each is the same iterator. listIterator doesn't differ from plain iterator in means of getting next object from a list.

Answer (score 0):

You can use iterator, which returned by `iterator` method. It doesn't require O(n) time to go to next item. It uses `ListIterator` implementation from `LinkedList` so it's fast.

Comment: How do you know? (It doesn't say so in the API)

Comment: @PLane just look at the sources

Comment: @PLane, yes I looked in source as Sean said

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Iterator`, it gives you a faster access. A sample code for a list:

```
 List<String> list = new LinkedList<String>();
    list.add("First");
    list.add("Second");
    list.add("Third");
    list.add("Fourth");

    Iterator it = list.iterator();

    while(it.hasNext())
    {
        System.out.println(it.next());
    }
```